# Make Div and its content only responsive in width?

Tags: html, css

First of all im a bit confused but i will do my best to explain my problem and what i want.

I have a div and inside that div i have another div, i want that div to move to left and right, nothing more, it has to follow the same path as the image when resizing (see my project).

How do i make that div that is behind the white circle always do the same path as the circle ?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
}

body > div {
  height: 200px;
}



.header { 
  background-color: transperent;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.product {
 
  margin-top:0px;
  height: 600px;
   background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.product2 {
  height: 600px;
  margin-top:0px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width:50%;
  float:left; 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.product2 img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main{
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Y5hHusa.png");
 height:650px;
}

#crew {
  height:50px;
  clear:both;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.tour {
  background-color: black;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.pricing {
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

.contact {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-top: -5px;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

.menu li a {
    color: blue;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 23px;
}
 
.menu li a:hover{
 background-color:none;
 color:red;
}

.div_form {

height:35%;
width:40%;
margin-top:36%;
margin-left:41%;
background-color:blue;
}

.product2 .div_form{

}

.product2 .div_form .form_title{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
margin-top:270px;
margin-left:1em;
font-size:3em
}

.product2 .div_form .form_circulo{

z-index:1
}

.product2 .div_form .div_email .input_first_email{
margin-top: -70%;
margin-left:50%;
height:3em;
border-radius:5px;
padding:1em;
width:45%; 
}

.product2 .div_form .divbtnsubmit{
background-color:red;
margin-left:60%;
width:20em;
height:3em;
border-radius:1em;
text-align:center;
margin-top:1em;
width:45%
}

.product2 .div_form .divbtnsubmit .btnsumnitform
{
font-size:2em;
color:white;
position:absolute;
padding:.3em;
margin-left:-3.5em
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
  <title> Layout </title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/48nYArD.png">
  
  <ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="#">Home &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Product Tour&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Try&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>            
   </ul>
</div>

  <div class="product">
  </div>
  <div class="product2">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3UTs03w.png">
  <div class="div_form">
     
     </div>        
  </div>                   
  </div>
   </div>
    
  <div id="crew">
  </div>
  <div class="tour">
  </div>
  <div class="pricing">
  </div>
  <div class="contact">
</body>
</html>
```

PS: Sorry for argumentation, my english isnt the best, hope you can understand.
Regards,
Duarte Andrade.

Comment: Oh, you mean why is `margin-top` in % a percentage of the width rather than the height. Yes, that's just how it is. If you want to give it a fixed position with regards to the height, use `position` and `top`. Or, since `.product2` has a height in pixels, you can just use a margin in pixels.

Comment: Could you explain better ? What i have wrong and how i have to do, i couldnt get your explanation, sorry.

Comment: I posted an answer; hope this explains things! Oh, and I simplified it somewhat by removing the things that don't matter to the question, making the issue more clear. Someone is already trying to close this question because it isn't clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to position the `div_form` div vertically by giving it a `margin-top` of `36%`. But a margin with a value in `%` is always relative to the width of the container, not the height. See the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_CSS_layout_model_-_boxes_borders_margins_padding).

The simplest solution is, because you know the height of the container (`product2`) is 600px, is to set the margin to 36% of 600px, or 216px.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.product {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.product2 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.product2 img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.div_form {
  height: 35%;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 216px; /* This is what I changed */
  margin-left: 41%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">

    <div class="product">
    </div>
    <div class="product2">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3UTs03w.png">
      <div class="div_form">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you really need a percentage of the parent's height, you would remove the margins and give the div `position:absolute` in the same way as the `img`. Then you can use `left:41%; top:36%;` but you will also need to experiment with the z-indexes a bit to get their stacking order right again.